# Make rpm package without any dependencies. However when the rpm package is installed in the environment, there is a problem of missing dependencies

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

Make rpm package without any dependencies. However when the rpm package is installed in the environment, there is a problem of missing dependencies

I use “ --nodeps --force” to ignore rpm install errors, but what is the root cause？

problem of missing dependencies:

```
#  rpm -ivh 3cbb43448c0ad96c2c44ee01a7357cd248647f92e7ebc71531c26acacbe59d90.rpm 
Error: Dependency detection failed:
ld-linux-aarch64.so.1()(64bit) is tool-dawn-tce-deploy-1.0.5-20220318.114629.4e054de.x86_64 need
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is tool-dawn-tce-deploy-1.0.5-20220318.114629.4e054de.x86_64 need
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is tool-dawn-tce-deploy-1.0.5-20220318.114629.4e054de.x86_64 need
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is tool-dawn-tce-deploy-1.0.5-20220318.114629.4e054de.x86_64 need
```

rpm spec:

```
Name: tool-dawn-tce-deploy
Version: %{component_version}
Release: %{component_release}
Summary: tool-dawn-tce-deploy
Group: Applications/System
License: ASL 2.0
BuildArch: x86_64

%description
Dawn tools，Contains product atomic operations and deployment seq

%prep
git clone git@git.woa.com:tce.ted/ted.dawn.git -b release/tce3.8.0
mv ted.dawn/tool/tool-dawn-tce-deploy ./tool-dawn-tce-deploy
rm -rf ted.dawn

%build
#nothing required

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
cp -rf ./tool-dawn-tce-deploy %{buildroot}%{_bindir}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{_bindir}/tool-dawn-tce-deploy
%pre

%post

%preun

%postun

%check

%clean

%changelog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is to disable the [internal dependency generator](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/FilteringAutomaticDependencies):

```
%global _use_internal_dependency_generator 0
```

That said, your binary will not work unless you make sure those libraries are somehow accessible to it.

If you want it to have no dependency *and* not ship the libraries inside the package, you need to build it statically. E.g. `-static` option for `gcc`.

Comment: What I packaged as rpm is a folder with no dependencies declared. Does it traverse all the files in the "%files" folder when building, find the binary files in it, and automatically add dependencies.
    So even though I didn't declare the dependencies in the rpm spec, the binaries were present in my packaged folder.. the dependencies were added automatically

Comment: @zekee yes, basically that's exactly how it works, by default.